# MS Access Query to filter out students

Tags: mysql, ms-access-2010

Basically I'm trying to create a query of all active students by a certain subprogram. Now there are certain students in "CBB" I don't want in my query. How can i do this query and taking these students dont want in it or the few that I need to be in query?

```
SELECT [Student Contact].[First Name], [Student Contact].[Last Name], [Student Contact].BannerID,
       [Basic Milestones].[Subprogram/ Training Area], [Basic Milestones].Adv1,
       [Student Contact].Status
FROM [Basic Milestones] INNER JOIN
     [Student Contact]
      ON [Basic Milestones].BannerID = [Student Contact].BannerID
WHERE ((([Basic Milestones].[Subprogram/ Training Area])="Biology" Or
        ([Basic Milestones].[Subprogram/ Training Area])="Behavioral and Cognitive Neuroscience" Or 
        ([Basic Milestones].[Subprogram/ Training Area])="Neuro (B) " Or
        ([Basic Milestones].[Subprogram/ Training Area])="CBB") AND (([Student Contact].Status)="active"));
```

Comment: what are the "Certain" CBB students?

Comment: Since your criteria has 'CBB', please explain how you want to exclude certain ones? i.e. Age > 22? Gender = 'F'?

Comment: Exclude them by advisers they are affiliated with like "john doe" "mary jane".

Comment: add something like `AND (Advisor <> "John Doe")` to the `WHERE` clause